# Статический класс или синглтон

Tags: c#, ооп, static, singleton

Добрый день.

Есть, например, класс:

```
public class ClassX 
{
    public string S1 = "s1";
    public string S2 = "s2";
    ...
}
```

Поля данного класса во время выполнения программы изменяются. Поля данного класса *используются различными объекты*. Читал, что для изменяемых данных не следует использовать статические классы. 
Как лучше реализовать? С применением синглтон паттерна? Мне показалось, что использовать синглтон будет слишком "громоздко" для такого простого класса...

Comment: Мне непонятно ни что вы хотите сделать, ни изначальной задачи, ни способа, которым вы хотите имплементить синглтон, ни чем он вам поможет, ни причем тут статические классы и изменяемость

Comment: Если у вас нет конкурентного доступа к данным, то смело используйте статику. Если есть, то используйте потокобезопасный синглтон

Comment: @rjhdby есть и другие варианты синглтона, почему вы решили, что один из этих двух подойдет или что автору вопроса вообще этот синглтон нужен?

Comment: @tym32167 поля вышенаписанного класса используются различными объектами по -- для глобальности напишу так -- всей программе. Данные в классе изменяются во время выполнения программы, исходя из различных действий.
Вопрос: как правильнее будет реализовать этот класс? - как статический или с применением паттерна синглтона?

Comment: @tym32167 вопрос про способ реализации синглтона не задавался.

Comment: Собственно, лучший вариант как это сделать вам уже подсказал @PashaPash

Answer (score 6):

Лучше не использовать ни статику, ни классический синглтон. И у статики, и у синглтона есть один общий недостаток - они достаточно жёстко привязывают к себе зависящий от них код. Т.е. юнит тесты на них вы не напишете, в отдельный проект нормально не перенесёте, прорефакторить еще как-то не сможете.

Выделите для "статического" класса обычный нестатический интерфейс, напишите для него обычную нестатическую реализацию. И вставьте ее в качестве зависимости в код используя любой IoC-контейнер (IServiceCollection для ASP.NET Core, Autofac, StructureMap, любой другой). И предоставьте контроль за единственностью экземпляра контейнеру.